# Is "used" an auxiliary verb in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

> She used to be a varsity athlete.

In a grammar book, the above sentence was listed among sentences containing at least one auxiliary verb. If "used" is indeed the auxiliary verb, can an infinitive be used as a main verb? Something seems off here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The verb is "use", not "used to". (The bracketing with, for example, past tense "used" is "[I used [to smoke"]]. It's an auxiliary verb for some speakers, but a lexical verb for most. It all depends on whether you can say "Used you to live near there?" and "It usedn't to be allowed"..

Comment: @BillJ Well, I agree, ***but*** there's also *usedta*, clearly alluded to but not actually listed in footnote 34 of page 1227 of CGEL, which is one of the verbs studied in Pullum's "*The morpholexical nature of to-contraction*". There's some lighthearted discussion on Language Log, [here](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2756). It's definitely one word for some users sometimes.

Comment: @BillJ It doesn't '**all** depend'. There are different tests one can use; emphasis is on _used to_ not _used_ in stressed speech, arguing for cohesiveness. I can't wait for the next great work on grammar that eclipses CGEL, and wonder if its adherents will be as dismissive of other approaches as some now are.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I'm aware of the pronunciation quirk. Grammatically, the "to" belongs in the clause functioning as complement of "use", just as it does with any other verb. The fact is that if the examples I gave are acceptable, then the auxiliary classification is OK. But for those who don't accept them, it can only be a lexical verb. As far as CGEL is concerned, we had the sort if grammar you're alluding to -- it was called the Comprehensive (Quirk et al) and look what we got. A lot of woolly analyses and awful examples that were of no use to anyone. Thank God for CGEL -- long may it reign.

Comment: @BillJ 'It can only be ...'. The splitting / lumping debate will doubtless continue for many years (if we have that long left). CGEL is happy to split FANBOYS (and few serious linguists would argue there); ing-forms on the N ... V cline and verbs functioning in 'auxiliary positions' are areas some deem worthy of better refinement. // Grammar differences set aside, have a good Christmas (I'll not offer to play football).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. And you.

Answer (score 7):

There's up to three auxiliary verbs in your sentence, depending on what grammar you subscribe to, or who you pay your dues to, as Professor Lawler used to say.

The verb *used* **is** sometimes an auxiliary verb for some speakers. It's not possible to say whether it is in your sentence because there is no subject-auxiliary inversion and no negation and no ellpsis.

The word *to* is considered a non-finite auxiliary verb by many grammarians, for example in HPSG, Sign-Based Construction Grammar and by authors like Geoffrey K Pullum.

Lastly, the verb *be* is considered an auxiliary by most modern grammarians even when used without a following verb (i.e. when used in a copula construction as in your example, where *be* is taking a noun phrase as a predicative complement). So - take your pick!

Regarding your second question, "main verb" is a bit passé nowadays. However, seeing as verbs like *ought* are considered auxiliaries and take *to*-infinitives, it shouldn't be a problem with *used*. The main criteria for auxiliariness make no reference to the form of the complement of the verb, and thus we don't need to consider it here.

Comment: "X used to be" cannot be an auxiliary. What would it be "helping"? And what is the sentence's verb?

Comment: @Lambie Etymological fallacy. [Also "*X used to be*" cannot be an auxiliary because it is four words!] And there's no use busting me about this, I'm just letting you know what the grammarians say about these items!

Comment: But my idea is not etymology. It's semantic. Yes, x used to [verb], sure.

Comment: @Lambie Some speakers accept sentences like "Used he to live there?". In sentences like that, the verb *use* undergoes subject-auxiliary inversion and is thus an auxiliary. Huddleston & Pullum mention this usage; I think I've heard it before but it strikes me as extremely uncommon.

Comment: @alphabet That is really specious. H&P often go overboard.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Is the "Used To" dissertation link still available? I was planning to read it but can no longer see it here.

Comment: I don't think citing GKP's classification of "to" as a verb is helpful here. It's never been widely accepted, and in any case it's irrelevant (i.e. off-topic) to the OP's question, which was simply about whether the aspectual verb "use" is an auxiliary verb or a lexical one. Much prefer RDH's analysis.

Comment: I regard 'used to' as unary, auxiliary (call it quasi-auxiliary, as with quasi-modal like 'ought to' if you like, as it doesn't behave exactly like 'have' say ... and is periphrastic) in that, like 'do' say or modals like 'can / should ...' it takes many infinitives/infinitive clauses as complement.